# Properties of the largest argument satsifying an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a \in [1/2, 1]$ and $b > 0$. Let $x \in [0,1]$ be the largest in value in $[0,1]$ such that $$ x (x-a)^2 \leq b.$$
I want to show that $x \geq  a$ always holds (irrespective of the specific choice of $a$ and $b$).

It seems very intuitive, but I stuggle with finding a proper argument. I also have difficulties with characterizing the $x$ in more detail.

**Edit**: Riemann already answered the question above. I'd like to refine the question:

*Show that $x > a$ always holds.*

Comment: The inequality always holds if $x=a$. Hence the largest one must be greater or equal to $a$.

Comment: Ah, missed the obvious, thanks! While it was not my original question, what if I want to show that $x > a$?

Comment: When $a=1$, that does not hold. If $a<1$, then you can argue by the continuity of the polynomial $x(x-a)^2$.

Comment: Ok, you answered all my question :D Thanks!